# Blinded + casting a spell with a bonus action + Find Familiar

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars, spellcasting, targeting, blind

Here's the setup:

- My familiar is adjacent to a target.
- I use my action to use my familiar's senses. I'm now blinded and deafened.
- I use a bonus action to cast a touch spell. My familiar uses its reaction to deliver the spell (which requires an melee spell attack roll).

Normally, being blinded causes you to attack at disadvantage, but I can use my familiar's senses.

Do I attack at disadvantage?

Background reading:

[If I'm blinded, can I cast a spell that doesn't require that the target be "a creature you can see"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/83373/casting-while-blinded-in-dd-5e)  (mentions casting while blind, but not specifically the issue of a familiar delivering a touch spell)

Comment: I don't believe there are any touch range, bonus action spells that involve an attack roll. If you multiclassed into Sorcerer and used Quickened Spell this could happen though, or if you just use an action spell on the next turn

Comment: @Medix2 It would have to be a quickened spell, not just an action on the next turn, because your view through your familiar's senses ends at the start of your next turn.

Comment: @RyanCThompson There's always Action Surge, if you need these two things to happen on the same turn.

Comment: Your related question: [Blind Familiar trying to deliver a touch spell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165253/blind-familiar-trying-to-deliver-a-touch-spell). I'd also like to ask the same question I asked there: "I assume the spell in question requires an attack roll? Your mention of attacking at disadvantage seems to imply it but you don't specify that restriction beforehand."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No, you attack normally.

You're using your familiar's senses and your familiar can see them just fine.

However, you don't need to use your familiar's senses, because the familiar delivers the spell as if they had cast it. This means the familiar, not you, must be within touch range of the target, have an unblocked path, and be able to see the target. Since you don't need to use your action to borrow their senses, this method also works for spells that require your action.

(Which is just as well since there are no bonus action spells with touch range that make spell attacks at the time they're cast.)

Comment: You could potentially support this as the sense sharing ability on blinds/deafens **with regard to your own senses** and not for anything else